# L. Evans' book PDE, what is the meaning of $D^2$ in the inequality?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In L. Evans' book PDE, 2nd Ed, p. 20, the auther denotes the gradient of some scalar field $u$ as $Du$, but I don't understand what he means by $D^2$ in the second inequality p. 22
$$
|D\Phi(x)| \leq \frac{C}{|x|^{n-1}},\quad|D^2 \Phi(x)|\leq  \frac{C}{|x|^n} \quad (x \neq 0)
$$
If anyone certainly knows what he means, please explain. It is not the divergence by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$D^2\Phi(x)$ is the Hessian of $\Phi$ (the matrix of all second-order partials. Then $|D^2\Phi(x)|^2$ is just the sum of the squares of the second order partials (see Appendix A in Evans, under "Notations for derivatives":

$$|D^2\Phi(x)|^2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^n (u_{x_ix_j}(x))^2.$$

Note that this is just the Frobenius norm of the Hessian. By equivalence of finite-dimensional norms, you can in fact take any matrix norm. For instance, you could take the matrix $p$-norm, i.e., the greatest entry in absolute value:

$$|D^2\Phi(x)| = \sup_{i,j} |u_{x_ix_j}(x)|,$$

with the only difference being in the constant $C$. This may be easier to work with in this case.